# need to join getent command in bash script

Tags: bash

I have task to list all running mariadb process in couple of hosts and in the end to have instance name (instance name is equal user which is running process)
I was able to write a script for it (below).
But in this case in some of the hosts username/instance_name is equal number for example 3124855. In this case i know that command  getent passwd 3124855 |cut -d':' -f1 can print for me correct user name not in numbers. The question how to put this command to the script to get correct user name all the time?

```
#!/bin/sh
result=$(ps -ef|grep "mysqld"|grep -v grep|awk '{print $8}')
if [ -z "${result}" ] ; then
  echo "no_instances"
  exit 0
else
  OIFS=$IFS
  IFS=$'\n'
  for i in $(ps -ef|grep "mysqld"|grep -v grep);  do
    if [[ $(`echo $i|awk '{print $8}'` --version) == *"MariaDB"* ]]; then
      echo $i|awk '{print $1}'
    fi
  done
  IFS=$OIFS
fi
```

Comment: `sh` is usually not `bash`.

Comment: Use http://shellcheck.net to check your code before posting it here

Answer (score 0):

You can force ps to output the numeric uid, so you will always have a numeric user wich you can then convert into a user name.

See the manual page of ps.

For example, use ps -eo ruid,cmd

The positional arguments for awk will then be $1 for the numeric userid and $2 for the cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
result=$(ps -ef|grep "mysqld"|grep -v grep|awk '{print $8}')
if [ -z "${result}" ] ; then
  echo "no_instances"
  exit 0
else
  OIFS=$IFS
  IFS=$'\n'
  for i in $(ps -ef|grep "mysqld"|grep -v grep);  do
    if [[ $(`echo $i|awk '{print $8}'` --version) == *"MariaDB"* ]]; then
      [ -z $(echo "${i}" | awk '{print $1}' | sed -r 's/^[0-9]+$//g') ] && echo $(getent passwd ${i} | cut -d':' -f1) || echo $i|awk '{print $1}'
    fi
  done
  IFS=$OIFS
fi
```

Constriction `[ -z $(echo "${i}" | awk '{print $1}' | sed -r 's/^[0-9]+$//g') ]` will check if UID has only digits. If it's true, code  `&& echo $(getent passwd ${i} | cut -d':' -f1)` will be executed. If it's false, script run `|| echo $i|awk '{print $1}'`